# How does the POST request look with this example data?

Tags: http, post, request

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.mypage.com/login.php" name="acc">
    <input value="mylogin" name="login" size="19" maxlength="30" type="text">
    <input maxlength="40" type="password" size="19" name="pass">
</form>
```

What is the encoded POST request? is it `login=mylogin&pass=mypassword` or should I use something with acc which is the name of form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_POST["name"] to receive a variable name from POST form. The name of form isn't necessary to receive arguments from it.